# Change forEachRDD

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am having a problem, we are using Kafka and spark.

we are using forEachRDD like this:

```
  messages.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
  val newRDD = rdd.map{message => 
                                  processMessage(message)}
  println(newRDD.count())
}
```

but we are passing the processMessage(message) method. This method will call a class that is creating the sparkContext. I have been reading and it will throw an error if you created the sparkContext inside the foreachRDD.

I have changed it like this:

```
    messages.map{
       case (msg) => 
           val newRDD3 = (processMessage(msg))
           (newRDD3)              
    }
```

but I am not sure if this is doing the same as the foreachRDD.

Could you please help me with this?

Any help will be really appreciate it.

Comment: You can use mapPartitions instead of map. And don't use foreachRDD.

Comment: We can consume multiple messages, do you think this will work the same as the foreachRDD?

Comment: Yes, it consumes messages from each partitions and will be more efficient than map transformation. Before applying mapPartitions repartition your DStream to desired partitions like val partitionedMessages = messages.repartition(10) and then apply mapPartitions to your partitionedMessages.

Comment: Thank you, we have this, InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], how can I convert each ConsumerRecord[String, String], to iterator[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code for ConsumerRecord[String, String] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in the solution.

For messages(InputDStream) I use foreachRDD, which convert it to a RDD, next use map to get the json from the consumerRecord. Next, convert the RDD to an Array[String] and pass it to the processMessage method.

```
    messages.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
      val newRDD = rdd.map{message => 
                             val req_message = message.value()  
                             (message.value())
                          }

      println("Request messages: " + newRDD.count())
      var resultrows = newRDD.collect()//.collectAsList() 
      processMessage(resultrows, mlFeatures: MLFeatures)          

    }
```

Inside the processMessage method, there is a for loop to process all the strings. Also we are inserting the request message and response message to a hbase table.

```
def processMessage(message: Array[String], mlFeatures: MLFeatures) = {

  for (j <- 0 until message.size){
        val req_message = message(j)//.get(j).toString() 

        val decisionTree_res = PriorAuthPredict.processPriorAuthPredict(req_message,mlFeatures)

        println("Message processed is " + req_message)

        kafkaProducer(conf.getString("kafka.responsetopic"), decisionTree_res)

        var startTime  = new Date().getTime();      
        saveToHBase(conf.getString("hbase.tableName"), req_message, decisionTree_res) 
        var endTime    = new Date().getTime();
        println("Kafka Consumer savetoHBase took : "+ (endTime - startTime) / 1000 + " seconds")            
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use sparksession

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                        .setAppName("appName")
                        .setMaster("local");

       SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
                                   .builder()
                                   .config(conf)
                                  .getOrCreate();
        return sparkSession;
```

Comment: Thank you Mario, we are using the sparksession.

Comment: The problem is that we are using the foreachRDD but the processmessage method is calling the class that is creating the sparkcontext and sparksession.  I want to change the foreachRDD with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I created the streamContext, then declare the topic and the KafkaParams.

Finally, I created the messages. Please see code below:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val date_today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
val date_today_hour = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH");
val PATH_SEPERATOR = "/";

val conf = ConfigFactory.load("spfin.conf")
println("kafka.duration --- "+ conf.getString("kafka.duration").toLong)

val mlFeatures: MLFeatures = new MLFeatures()

// Create context with custom second batch interval
//val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SpFinML")
//val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(conf.getString("kafka.duration").toLong))

val ssc = new StreamingContext(mlFeatures.sc, Seconds(conf.getString("kafka.duration").toLong))

// Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
val topicsSet = conf.getString("kafka.requesttopic").split(",").toSet

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> conf.getString("kafka.brokers"),
  "zookeeper.connect" -> conf.getString("kafka.zookeeper"),
  "group.id" -> conf.getString("kafka.consumergroups2"),
  "auto.offset.reset" -> conf.getString("kafka.autoOffset"),
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (conf.getString("kafka.autoCommit").toBoolean: java.lang.Boolean),
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "security.protocol" -> "SASL_PLAINTEXT")

 /*    this code is to get messages from request topic*/
 val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams))

    messages.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
      val newRDD = rdd.map{message => 
                                      processMessage(message,"Inside processMessage")}
      println("Inside map")
 //          println(newRDD.count())
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The processMessage method is this:

I think I might need to change this method, right?

```
 def processMessage(message: ConsumerRecord[String, String],msg: String): ConsumerRecord[String, String] = {

    println(msg)
    println("Message processed is " + message.value())

    val req_message = message.value()

    //val tableName = conf.getString("hbase.tableName")

    //println("Hbase table name : " + tableName)

    //val decisionTree_res = "PredictionModelOutput "
    //      val decisionTree_res = PriorAuthPredict.processPriorAuthPredict(req_message)
   //      println(decisionTree_res)
   //
   //      kafkaProducer(conf.getString("kafka.responsetopic"), decisionTree_res)

   kafkaProducer(conf.getString("kafka.responsetopic"), """[{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"'66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"'9427535101","serviceDate":"20161102","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":22957.55,"daysOrUnits":140,"algorithmType":"LR ,RF ,NB ,VoteResult","label":0.0,"prediction":"0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0","finalPrediction":"Approved","rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":0,"probability":"0.9307022947278968 - 0.06929770527210313 ,0.9879908798891663 - 0.012009120110833629 ,1.0 - 0.0 ,","patientGender":"M","invoiceId":0,"therapyClass":"REMODULIN","patientAge":52,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":0,"refillNo":0,"requestId":"419568891","requestDateTime":"20171909213055","responseId":"419568891","responseDateTime":"201801103503"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9427535101","serviceDate":"20160829","responseDate":"20161020","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":1,"invoiceId":46347660,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":2,"authExpiry":"20170218","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"A"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9427535101","serviceDate":"20160829","responseDate":"20161020","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":2,"invoiceId":46347660,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":2,"authExpiry":"20170211","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"A"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9427535101","serviceDate":"20160714","responseDate":"20160908","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":3,"invoiceId":45631877,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":1,"authExpiry":"20170218","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"A"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9427535101","serviceDate":"20160714","responseDate":"20160908","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":4,"invoiceId":45631877,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":1,"authExpiry":"20170211","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"A"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9427535101","serviceDate":"20160621","responseDate":"20160818","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":19677.9,"daysOrUnits":120,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":5,"invoiceId":45226407,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":0,"authExpiry":"20170218","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"A"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9427535101","serviceDate":"20160829","responseDate":"20161020","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":6,"invoiceId":46347660,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":2,"authExpiry":"20170218","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"P"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9450829801","serviceDate":"20160829","responseDate":"20161020","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":7,"invoiceId":46347660,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":2,"authExpiry":"20170211","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"P"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9450829801","serviceDate":"20160829","responseDate":"20161020","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":8,"invoiceId":46347660,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":2,"authExpiry":"20170218","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"P"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9427535101","serviceDate":"20160829","responseDate":"20161020","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":9,"invoiceId":46347660,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":2,"authExpiry":"20170211","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"P"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9556908,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9450829801","serviceDate":"20160714","responseDate":"20160908","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":26237.2,"daysOrUnits":160,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":10,"invoiceId":45631877,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1174215,"refillNo":1,"authExpiry":"20170211","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"P"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":4879911,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9818182501","serviceDate":"20160901","responseDate":"20161027","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":13118.6,"daysOrUnits":80,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":11,"invoiceId":46419758,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1095509,"refillNo":7,"authExpiry":"20170626","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"O"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":4056274,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"8914616801","serviceDate":"20160727","responseDate":"20161019","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":13118.6,"daysOrUnits":80,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":12,"invoiceId":45820271,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1055447,"refillNo":10,"authExpiry":"-","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"O"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":3476365,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9262852501","serviceDate":"20160809","responseDate":"20161013","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":30,"placeOfService":12,"charges":16398.25,"daysOrUnits":100,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":13,"invoiceId":46027459,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1169479,"refillNo":2,"authExpiry":"20161231","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"O"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":1064449,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"9327540001","serviceDate":"20160825","responseDate":"20161013","serviceBranchId":35,"serviceDuration":14,"placeOfService":12,"charges":6559.3,"daysOrUnits":40,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":14,"invoiceId":46303200,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":714169,"refillNo":0,"authExpiry":"20170112","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"O"},{"payorId":53723,"therapyType":"RMIV","ndcNumber":"66302010201","patientId":9205248,"procedureCode":"J3285","authNbr":"0000000","serviceDate":"20160823","responseDate":"20161013","serviceBranchId":65,"serviceDuration":20,"placeOfService":12,"charges":6559.3,"daysOrUnits":40,"algorithmType":"NN","label":0.0,"rejectOutcome":"Y","neighborCounter":15,"invoiceId":46257476,"patientAge":0,"npiId":0,"prescriptionId":1206606,"refillNo":0,"authExpiry":"-","exceedFlag":"N","appealFlag":"N","authNNType":"O"}]""")

  //saveToHBase(conf.getString("hbase.tableName"), req_message, decisionTree_res)

  message
}
```